# Употребление предлога "к"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Нужно ли использовать предлог  *к* в следующем предложении:

> Напомните мне, пожалуйста, *к* какой кафедре относился усопший профессор?

Поверхностный поиск по интернету не дал никаких результатов, а использовать общие правила употребления предлогов я не умею.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно "относился" требует предлога ***К***. В таких случаях, если сомневаетесь, попробуйте задавать вопрос. Относился "к чему".

Без предлога можно использовать, например, глагол "принадлежать".

Но по контексту, если это не прямая речь немного неотесанного героя, куда лучше спросить "на какой кафедре трудился?".

И *относиться к*, и *принадлежать* - по отношению к кафедре - отдает чем-то неуважительным к профессору.

Comment: "...отдает чем-то неуважительным к профессору". Тем более к усопшему.